# Keygen: Redirecting after certificate delivery?

Tags: html, html5-keygen

When using an HTML5 keygen element, the form posts (among others) a certificate signing request (in SPKAC format) to the server.  The server then sends the corresponding certificate with mime-type application/x-x509-user-cert.  I implemented this without problems.

My problem now is how I can continue the flow, deliver the certificate and redirect to another page.  I tried two things and both failed:  (this is flask code)

```
r = Response(userCert, status=302, mimetype='application/x-x509-user-cert')  
r.headers['Location'] = url_for('index') 

r = Response(userCert, mimetype='application/x-x509-user-cert')  
r.headers['Refresh'] = "1; url=%s" % url_for('index')
```

In the former case, the browser fails to install the certificate, but redirects correctly;
In the latter case, the browser (FF) installs the certificate, but fails to go to the new page.

Comment: In the meantime, I also tried a mime multipart response with both, subtype "mixed" and "mixed-replace", respectively.  The former attempt doesn't seem to do much, in the latter, I get a file save dialog...

Answer (score 0):

After A LOT of banging my head against the wall, I finally found a way that is half way usable:

I launch the page with the form that contains the keygen element from another html page.  The keygen page submits on load;  and the parent page closes the keygen page after a timeout.

Not certain what happens if the timeout is too short though.  But I didn't find any event that indicates that a certificate has been loaded...